# how can I maintain sequence of my list using set?

Tags: python, list, sorting, set, sequence

```
In [1]: l1 = ['a',2,3,0,9.0,0,2,6,'b','a']

In [2]: l2 = list(set(l1))

In [3]: l2
Out[3]: ['a', 0, 2, 3, 6, 9.0, 'b']
```

Here you can see the the list l2 is falling with different sequence then the original l1, I need to remove the duplicate elements from my list without changing the sequence/order of the list elements....

Comment: @carl - Eh? That question involves duplicates in a list of lists. This is just a list, but he wants to make it unique it without getting rid of it's internal ordering...

Comment: "how can I maintain sequence of my list using set?" Sets are **unordered** by definition

Comment: @advait Regarding my answer - Thanks, I honestly didn't know if it would hold or not. It was 6am in the morning, so I didn't really feel like booting up python. Tempted to change the answer to use ordered dictionaries, but I'm not too familiar with them so I'll just delete the answer I think.

Comment: @Stephen, I added a version using OrderedDict to my answer

Answer (score 15):

If you are not concerned with efficiency, this is O(n*m)

```
>>> sorted(set(l1), key=l1.index)
['a', 2, 3, 0, 9.0, 6, 'b']
```

Using an intermediate dict is more complicated, but is O(n+m*logm)

where n is the number of elements in l1 and m is the number of unique elements in l1

```
>>> l1 = ['a',2,3,0,9.0,0,2,6,'b','a']
>>> d1=dict((k,v) for v,k in enumerate(reversed(l1)))
>>> sorted(d1, key=d1.get, reverse=True)
['a', 2, 3, 0, 9.0, 6, 'b']
```

In Python3.1 you have OrderedDict so it's very easy

```
>>> l1 = ['a',2,3,0,9.0,0,2,6,'b','a'] 
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(l1))
['a', 2, 3, 0, 9.0, 6, 'b']
```

Answer (score 6):

You can solve it by defining a function like this:

```
def dedupe(items):
    seen = set()
    for item in items:
        if item not in seen:
            yield item
            seen.add(item)
```

To use it:

```
>>> l1 = ['a',2,3,0,9.0,0,2,6,'b','a']
>>> l2 = list(dedupe(l1))
>>> l2
['a', 2, 3, 0, 9.0, 6, 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is off the top of my head (using dicts):

```
l1 = ['a',2,3,0,9.0,0,2,6,'b','a']
l2 = []
s = {}
for i in l1:
    if not i in s:
        l2.append(i)
        s[i] = None

# l2 contains ['a', 2, 3, 0, 9.0, 6, 'b', 'a']
```

Edit: Using sets (also off the top of my head):

```
l1 = ['a',2,3,0,9.0,0,2,6,'b','a']
l2 = []
s = set()
for i in l1:
   if not i in s:
       l2.append(i)
       s.add(i)
```