# Remove duplicates without changing the order in two dimension list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

How could I remove duplicates two dimension list without changing the order?

```
list_j = [[100,2,3,3], [4,98,99,98], [5,99,98,4], [5,99,98,5], [100,99,98,100,100,6]]

list_pre = [list(set(i)) for i in list_j]
print(list_pre)

[[2, 3, 100], [98, 99, 4], [98, 99, 4, 5], [98, 99, 5], [98, 99, 100, 6]]
```

As you can see it changed the order. What I want is `[[100,2,3,],...]`

Desired output `[[100,2,3,], [4,98,99], [5,99,98,4], [5,99,98], [100,99,98,6]]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I maintain sequence of my list using set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562971/how-can-i-maintain-sequence-of-my-list-using-set)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to maintain the order of insertion of keys:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
list_j = [[100,2,3,3], [4,98,99,98], [5,99,98,4], [5,99,98,5], [100,99,98,100,100,6]]
output = [list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x)) for x in list_j]
```

gives

```
[[100, 2, 3], [4, 98, 99], [5, 99, 98, 4], [5, 99, 98], [100, 99, 98, 6]]
```

If you using Python 3.7 or higher, you can use normal dictionaries as well since they also maintain the order of insertion:

```
output = [list(dict.fromkeys(x)) for x in list_j]
```

Comment: @Javis - Spot on. Acutally, it depends on the Python version (>3.5)? You can get all `dict() items` guaranteed in the insert order.  So it could be:  [list(dict.fromkeys(ll)) for ll in list_j]

Answer (score 0):

Same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order):

```
def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]

list_j = [[100,2,3,3], [4,98,99,98], [5,99,98,4], [5,99,98,5], [100,99,98,100,100,6]]

list_pre = [f7(i) for i in list_j]

print(list_pre)
```

This will give the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def remove_duplicates(my_list):
    result_list = []
    for _list in my_list:
        result_list.append(sorted(set(_list), key=lambda ind: _list.index(ind)))
    return result_list
```